# Download file from server using URL

Tags: c#, download, webclient

I have a dot net mvc project where on the server side people generate reports. To allow downloading report from web, I have a function in controller that return File.

`public FilePathResult DownloadResult(int id)
    {`

```
     Result res = MyModel.GetResultById(id);

     if (res.DownloadPath != null)
     {
        return File(res.DownloadPath, "application/zip", Path.GetFileName(res.DownloadPath));
     }
}
```

Now I want to download the this file using WebClient

`WebClient wc = new WebClient();
    wc.DownloadFile("ServerUrl" + resultId, filename);`

My problem is to save the downloaded file with same name as returned by server. The DownloadResult method on controller returns File with name [as shown in code Path.GetFileName(res.DownloadPath)] but on the client side I don't know the name of file server is returning. I have to in turn give a local filename as param in wc.DownloadFile

Is there a way to know what filename server it returning so that i can save my file locally with the same name as on server.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could check the Httpheader that is returned:

Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=FILENAME

I'm not a 100% sure that mvc returns this, but I think when you return the FilePathResult you can set the Httpheader.

You could of course add this to your response:

```
Response.AppendHeader("Content-Disposition", "attachment; filename=" + Path.GetFileName(res.DownloadPath));
```

Comment: I tried getting response headers from webclient.ResponseHeaders and they are: 
[ <<<<
    X-AspNetMvc-Version
    Content-Length
    Cache-Control
    Content-Type
    Date
    Server
    X-AspNet-Version
    X-Powered-By
>>>>]

I could not find Content-Disposition here :(

Comment: You'd need to add the header yourself, see the edit in my answer for how to do that

Comment: Hi, I have added Response.AppendHeader just before returning the File in my MVC controller. Still I'm not able to see a header key with name "Content-Disposition". Do I need to change/modify at some other places as well?

Comment: If you send the request with a tool like Fiddler, can you see the header? Try that first, if you can see the header then probably WebClient is not reading the header correctly.

Comment: While debugging on the server I could see that header was added - {Server=Microsoft-IIS%2f7.5&X-AspNetMvc-Version=4.0&Content-Disposition=attachment%3b+filename%3dResult_3881_Report.Generic.zip} , but some how as you suggested webclient is not able to read the header correctly. Thanks.

Comment: You could try and use the HttpClient instead.

Comment: Or the HttpWebRequest class. I just found this page: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.webclient.headers.aspx which states that certain headers are blocked in the WebClient class